# Eclipse gradle and maven tooling - local resolution

Tags: eclipse, maven, gradle

I want to gradually migrate a multi-module maven build to a multi-module gradle build.

I'm currently using [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) maven tooling in eclipse and one feature I like is that if projectA depends on projectB and both projects are in my eclipse workspace, m2e is smart enough to use the local .class files for projectB instead of using the .jar file from my maven repository. Let's call this feature "local resolution".

So, can the eclipse gradle tooling and [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) play nicely together?

1. If a gradle project depends on a maven project, can the maven project be locally resolved
2. If a maven project depends on a gradle project, can the gradle project be locally resolved
3. If a gradle project depends on a gradle project, can the dependent gradle project be locally resolved?

Answer (score 4):

Resolving local gradle projects is blocked until [GRADLE-2750](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2750) is resolved. So the current state is this:

1. Local resolution works for gradle project depending on maven project (fixed in version 3.1.0.M1)
2. Local resolution fails for maven project depending on gradle project
3. Local resolution fails for gradle project depending on gradle project

Related STS issues

- [STS-2834](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2834)
- [STS-2405](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2405)
- [STS-2836](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2836)

**Update**

[GRADLE-2750](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2750) has been fixed and will be available in the next gradle release, Gradle 1.12.

Comment: I have the same "challenge" and was looking for a solution. Since I am still learning Gradle, most specifically Eclipse integration, I came to this. In my case I presently only need #1 from your list, which you say is supported, but I can't seem to find documentation as to how to do *that*. I am guessing it has to do with mavenLocal() for the repo, but what do I state for the version of a dependency? "local"?

Comment: You shouldn't need to tweak the version. I haven't done this myself but I assume that if you have a maven project in your eclipse workspace matching the id/version in your build.gradle then this will be used instead of the jar in your maven repo.

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming [composite build support](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/exciting-new-buildship-features-coming-up/14728) feature in the [buildship](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship) plugin sounds very promising.

From what I can see this will solve question 3.