# How do I get my gradle-managed Java project in eclipse to resolve imports?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

After migrating a minecraft plugin project of mine to a new workstation, the project builds (with buildship in Eclipse) but the IDE is telling me nearly every import in my projects source files can't be resolved. How do I get my project to recognize the imports?

Not sure if its relevant, but the original workstation/IDE was Eclipse Oxygen.3a release (4.7.3a) running on OSX 10.13.6. My new workstation is on Windows 10 and uses the Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0) IDE. I have checked several stackoverflow posts for a solution to no avail, although I suspect it has something to do with the gradle configuration for my project?

Two possible complications are:
- I import a shadowjar as a dependency which presumably exists in the same directory
- I import some external dependencies including junit-jupyter and the spongepowered.org api

Here's my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'


group = 'net.kevinmendoza.sedimentarysequences'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
description = 'Sedimentary Sequences'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = 'sponge'
        url = 'http://repo.spongepowered.org/maven'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.spongepowered:spongeapi:5.0.0'
    compile project(':GeoWorldLibrary')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0'
}
```

and the settings.gradle file

```
rootProject.name = 'SedimentarySequences'
include ':GeoWorldLibrary'
project(':GeoWorldLibrary').projectDir = new 
File(settingsDir,'../GeoWorldLibrary')
```

When I right click my project and click gradle>refresh dependencies, the console reports a "CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 0s", however the opened project in the IDE is still riddled with import errors which should be accessible from the above imports.

So, how do I go about fixing this stackoverflow?

Edit:
the two types of imports not resolved errors:

```
the import net.<myname>.<myownprojecwhichisadependency>.mypackage.classfile cannot be resolved
the import org.spongepowered could not be resolved
```

Comment: Could you provide some examples of import errors? e.g. the packages that are marked as missing?

Comment: sure thing. I'll add it to my main post

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this fixes your problem, but this often works for me:

Add `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` to your build.gradle file and then execute command `gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse` in cmd.

Comment: Tried it out. It lengthened the time to configure but did not resolve the problem.

Comment: @KEVINMENDOZA after doing this, did you import the project in eclipse as a "general project", not a gradle one?

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be recurrent with Eclipse and I am one struggling with it.
I am not experienced in the internals of eclipse/gradle/maven but the answer to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126415/eclipse-and-gradle-classpath-out-of-sync-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type) seems to be right because I had imported my gradle project by using the specific gradle importing option and got the problem everytime I added dependencies to build.gradle.
This time I deleted the project and imported it as a generic eclipse project by using "File -> Open Project from file system" and the importing resolution problems seem to have subsided.

I hope I am helping and not just adding to the confusion.