# Is it possible for Gradle projects in buildship to resolve dependencies to other Gradle projects in the same workspace?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

Copied from [Is it possible for Gradle projects in Eclipse/STS to resolve dependencies to other Gradle projects in the same workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282985/is-it-possible-for-gradle-projects-in-eclipse-sts-to-resolve-dependencies-to-oth)

A Gradle project in my workspace (call it Downstream) needs to depend on another Gradle project (call it Upstream). Outside of Eclipse, of course Upstream would need to be build and installed before Downstream (so that Gradle can resolve it). In Eclipse, since both projects are in the workspace together, I'd like to have Gradle look in the workspace first and make the dependency between the projects, not from the repo.

I'm nto using Eclipse/STS, but the shine new Eclipse-Buildship gradle integration. does anybody know how to do that essential feature?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment Buildship only supports importing one multiproject build and not multiple seperated gradle projects. This is planned to change but requires also some work in the Gradle Tooling API where we want to have the concept of a workspace modelled correctly. The gradle team started to specify this functionality in their design documents at

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/design-docs/ide-integration.md#story---expose-workspace-concept-for-eclipse